# Two Vector Tilesets with Mapbox Android SDK

Tags: android, maps, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am using Mapbox SDK for Android (Mapbox SDK version 9.x.x), and I am trying to use two vector tilesets at the same time. Idea was to add each vector tileset as a separate layer, similarly as it can be done with raster tilesets, but it looks impossible. Why?

Well:

```
val firstStyle = "https://path/to/first.json"
val secondStyle = "https://path/to/second.json"
mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromUri(firstStyle)) { style: Style ->

    val secondVectorSource = VectorSource("second", secondStyle)
    style.addSource(secondVectorSource)

    // #second
    val lineLayer = LineLayer("second", "second")
    lineLayer.setSourceLayer("internal-layer-from-second-style")
    lineLayer.setProperties(
        lineJoin(Property.LINE_JOIN_ROUND),
        lineCap(Property.LINE_CAP_ROUND),
        lineColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")),
        lineWidth(1.5f)
    )
    style.addLayer(lineLayer)
}
```

You see, vector styles have internal layers with different features, and loading and showing all of them seems possible only with `firstStyle`, when you pass it to `Style.Builder`. That way all of the internal layers of `firstStyle` become layers of the `Style`.

And that's it, once I build `style` using `Builder` I see no other way to add another vector tileset with all layers just like that.

What I *can* do is to create new `VectorSource` with `secondStyle`, but manually pick the layers from it (part I marked in my example as `#second`) and add it. And I need to be aware what kind of vector layer is it (in my example it was `LineLayer`)

I don't know how to generically just add both `firstStyle` and `secondStyle` tilesets, without messing with particular layers. I tried invoking twice `Style.Builder()` to make two styles manually, and merge them somehow, but `.build()` method is `private` inside SDK :)

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks